# Search the amount of unique value and how many times they appear

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal

I have a csv file with

```
value name   date   sentence    
0000  name1  date1  I want apples
0021  name2  date1  I want bananas
0212  name3  date2  I want cars
0321  name1  date3  I want pinochio doll
0123  name1  date1  I want lemon
0100  name2  date1  I want drums
1021  name2  date1  I want grape
2212  name3  date2  I want laptop
3321  name1  date3  I want Pot
4123  name1  date1  I want WC
2200  name4  date1  I want ramen
1421  name5  date1  I want noodle
2552  name4  date2  I want film
0211  name6  date3  I want games
0343  name7  date1  I want dvd
```

I want to find the unique value in the name tab (I know I have to use -f 2 but then I also want to know how many times they appear/the amount of sentence they made.

```
eg: name1,5
    name2,3
    name3,2
    name4,2
    name5,1
    name6,1
    name7,1
```

Then afterwards I want to make another data on how many people per appearence

```
1 appearance, 3
2 appearance ,2
3 appearance ,1
4 appearance ,0
5 appearance ,1
```

Comment: I think that the actual csv file looks a little bit different. Your example has 2 paces between two fields. Can you give the actual format (delimiter can be ','or ';' or '^') ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first part is using awk below

```
awk -F" " 'NR>1 { print $2 } ' jerome.txt  | sort | uniq -c
```

For the second part, you can pipe it through Perl and get the results as below

```
> awk -F" " 'NR>1 { print $2 } ' jerome.txt  | sort | uniq -c | perl -lane '{$app{$F[0]}++} END {@c=sort keys %app; foreach($c[0] ..$c[$#c]) {print "$_ appearance,",defined($app{$_})?$app{$_}:0 }}'
1 appearance,3
2 appearance,2
3 appearance,1
4 appearance,0
5 appearance,1
>
```

**EDIT1:**

Second part using a Perl one-liner

```
> perl -lane '{$app{$F[1]}++ if $.>1} END {$app2{$_}++ for(values %app);@c=sort keys %app2;foreach($c[0] ..$c[$#c]) {print "$_ appearance,",$app2{$_}+0}}' jerome.txt
1 appearance,3
2 appearance,2
3 appearance,1
4 appearance,0
5 appearance,1
>
```

Comment: Could you do it in a single perl. That would be a nice addition.

Comment: '@kvantour.. will give a try

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is a classic example of combining a set of core-tools of Linux in a pipeline:

This solves your first problem:

```
$ awk '(NR>1){print $2}' file | sort | uniq -c
      5 name1
      3 name2
      2 name3
      2 name4
      1 name5
      1 name6
      1 name7
```

This solves your second problem:

```
$ awk '(NR>1){print $2}' file | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -c
      1 5
      1 3
      2 2
      3 1
```

You notice that the formatting is a bit missing, but this essentially solves your problem.

Of course in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) you can do it in one go, but I do believe that you should try to understand the above line. Have a look at `man sort` and `man uniq`. The [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution is:

Problem 1:

```
awk '(NR>1){a[$2]++}END{ for(i in a) print i "," a[i] }' file
name6,1
name7,1
name1,4
name2,3
name3,2
name4,2
name5,1
```

Problem 2:

```
awk '(NR>1){a[$2]++; m=(a[$2]<m?m:a[$2])}
     END{ for(i in a) c[a[i]]++;
          for(i=1;i<=m;++i) print i, "appearance,", c[i]+0
     }' foo.txt
1 appearance, 3
2 appearance, 2
3 appearance, 1
4 appearance, 0
5 appearance, 1
```

Comment: the answer to part2 is missing.

Comment: @stack0114106 I did not understand what you mean with question 2. but now updated.

Comment: i meant the problem2.. so you did it now.. np

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st report, you can use:

```
tail -n +2 file | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c
   5 name1
   3 name2
   2 name3
   2 name4
   1 name5
   1 name6
   1 name7
```

For the 2nd report, you can use:

```
tail -n +2 file | awk '{print $2}'| sort | uniq -c | awk 'BEGIN{max=0} {map[$1]+=1; if($1>max) max=$1} END{for(i=1;i<=max;i++){print i" appearance,",(i in map)?map[i]:0}}'
1 appearance, 3
2 appearance, 2
3 appearance, 1
4 appearance, 0
5 appearance, 1
```

The complexity here is due to the fact that you wanted a `0` and custom text `appearance` in the output.

Comment: you can shorten the END block using END{for(i=1;i<=max;i++){print i" appearance, ", (i in map)?map[i] : 0}}

Comment: Edited the answer. Thanks!

Comment: What if i want to remove the "appearance" string and just print 1,2  2,100 3,21 and so on?

Comment: You can simply use `awk 'NR>1{print $2}' file | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c` then.